# javafx imageview heightProperty binding don't work

Tags: javafx, imageview, image-resizing, property-binding

i am facing problem to developed a demo JavaFX program for image viewing as a newbie. here i have an ImageView in BorderPane center position which is wrapped with a StackPane and VBox. where StackPane is always grow with VBox and i bind ImageView with StackPane Width and Height property so that my ImageView will change its setFitHeight and Weight when i resize window. it works fine as i want but problem is when window resized from maximum the image don't resize its Height. i found that StackPane's heightProperty change listener don't call.
So i to solve this problem to archive my goal.? is its some kinds JavaFX bug or my lacking knowledge?

## here is my fxml code for image view:

```
   <center>
  <VBox fx:id="imageVBox" alignment="CENTER" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets />
     </BorderPane.margin>
     <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="250.0" fitWidth="300.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" onDragDropped="#getDragImage" onDragOver="#dragOver" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" StackPane.alignment="CENTER">
           <viewport>
              <Rectangle2D />
           </viewport>
        </ImageView>
     </StackPane>
  </VBox>
```

## my java code which bind ImageView with StackPane:

```
        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty());
        imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty());
```

## the problem i faced:

1. my program window when i run it

[image: my program window when i run it]

2. maximize window

[image: maximize window]

3. when i resize it to default the problem occured, image don't resize as expected

[image: when i resize it to default the problem occured, image don't resize as expected]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, i found the problem from that post answer [JavaFX - BorderPane/StackPane not resizing after children changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949178/javafx-borderpane-stackpane-not-resizing-after-children-changed?rq=1) and the problem was that i didn't give StackPane any minimum size which is required to do the clipping. so i'm posting the answer if it helps someone.

## so my final solved binding code is like below:

```
stackPane.setMinSize(0, 0);
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stackPane.widthProperty());
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(stackPane.heightProperty());
```